# In what ways is four dimension relevant to modern physics?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions

In what fields can the consideration of four perpendicular vectors be useful to making theories and models in physics? Is the concept of four dimension restricted to spatial dimensions?

Comment: Our concept of spatial dimensions is still restricted to three dimension. In some of our theories we treat time like it's a dimension, which works for some things and doesn't for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already in use; Minkowski introduced the four dimensional geometry of spacetime shortly after Einstein's first papers on Special Relativity.  Three spacial and one temporal dimension;  the metric is not Euclidean, but instead is Lorentzian, with signature +++- or ---+, depending on choice of convention.

Higher dimensional spaces occur naturally I  mechanical systems, which have one dimension per degree of freedom; then the state of the system is completely specified by a single point and it's velocity in this space.

And quantum mehanics has a superabundance of situations demanding higher dimensional spaces, including ones with infinite dimensions.